# How to stop javascript from erasing my PHP session variable value?

Tags: javascript, php, session

I am developing a PHP web application. There is also Javascript for google maps in my webpage. When I log the user in, I set the `$_SESSION['userid']` variable to the id of the user.

There is some problem in my javascript code in the same webpage that when I refresh the page, the `$_SESSION['userid']` value gets erased somehow and the user is logged out automatically. This only happens when I refresh the page after logging in. (First time, when the user logs in, it works fine).

I debugged and the problem is in this code that is removing my `$_SESSION['userid']` variable.

```
   $.get('http://domain.com/rest/rest.php/geolocations', function(data) {

});
```

My API code at server side (PHP):

```
$app->get("/geolocations", function() use ($app)
    {
        try 
         {
            $geolocations = Model::factory('Geolocations')->find_many();
            foreach ($geolocations as $geolocation) {
                $user=Model::factory('Users')->where('id',$geolocation->user_id)->find_one();
                $response []= array(
                        'id'=>$geolocation->id,
                        'user_id'=>$geolocation->user_id,
                        'state' => $user->state,
                        'username' => $user->username,
                        'latitude'=>$geolocation->latitude,
                        'longitude'=>$geolocation->longitude,
                        'type_of_vehicle'=>$user->type_of_vehicle,
                        'number_plate'=>$user->number_plate,
                    );
            }
         } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
            {
                $status = "danger";
                $message = $e->getMessage();
                $response = array(
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $message
                );
            }
        $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        echo json_encode($response);

    });
```

Comment: JavaScript can't overwrite your session value

Comment: when i comment out this piece of code from my webpage, the sessions work fine. That brings me to the idea that somehow this javascript code is erasing my session value.

Comment: I promise you with 100% certainty that Javascript is not overwriting your session values. You have some server-side code that's overwriting that value or some server-side code killing your session or you're completely closing out of the browser. Suggesting your JS is clearing your session variable is like saying the guy who runs the copier deleted a file off of your computer because you sent a copy to the copier.

Comment: javascript has **NO** access to $_SESSION. But what javascript can do is erase the session COOKIE, causing the server to create a new/empty session.

Comment: Based on your edit, you have some code running at `http://domain.com/rest/rest.php/geolocations` which is messing with the session. Go check out what's running there or contact the API provider if that isn't your code.

Comment: i narrowed it down to one line of code thats causing it

Comment: sure that request is erasing any session variable, just debug on php side

Comment: I have added my API code to question

Comment: are you using session_start() at the top for all?

Comment: yes I am, at the top of every page

Comment: If I dont, the sessions are not held in $_SESSION variable